# Conditional Select in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, conditional-statements

I am working on a mysql query and its giving me headache!

**The Scenario:**

I am building a website where people can select industries they are interested in (NOTIFY_INDUSTRY). I join the selected values and store in a database field.

Example: a member selects agriculture (id = 9) and oil and gas (id = 13). I join them as 9-13 and store in the database. 
Users can select several industries, not limited to two.

Also, members can select an industry (COMPANY_INDUSTRY) it belongs in assuming Information Technology which is stored in the database too.

```
Sample table (members):

ID
EMAIL
COMPANY_NAME
COMPANY_INDUSTRY
NOTIFY_INDUSTRY
```

**The problem:**

When a new user registers on the website, mail (the mails are sent on daily basis) is sent to existing users who have the new user's industry (COMPANY_INDUSTRY) as one of their interested industries (NOTIFY_INDUSTRY).

**What i have done:**

```
$sql="select id, email
      from members
      where notify_industry in (
        select company_industry
        from members
        where datediff($today, date_activated) <= 1)"
```

This does not select the right members and i do not know the right way to go about it

**EDIT - Exact Problem with current output:**

Does not return any row, even when it should.

Assuming the new user's company_industry is 9, and there is an existing user with notify_industry: 10-9-20; it is meant to return the existing members email as the new member is in the existing member's categories of interest; but i get blanks

Comment: Can you show the output you expect and what you are getting? What is wrong about the output you are getting now exactly?

Comment: You should normalize the database. instead of saving `9-13`, save `9` and `13` in two different rows

Comment: in this scenario, what is the best way of normalizing the tables? If a user, is interested in 30 different categories, do i insert the 30 different categories in 30 diferent rows of a table and do same for all members? Please kindly illustrate

Comment: can company_industry be null?

Comment: @andy, yes company_industry can be null

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should redesign the tables, as others have suggested.

However, barring that, there is a gross hack you can do:

```
SET sql_mode = 'ANSI';

    SELECT notify_members.id, notify_members.email
      FROM members notify_members
INNER JOIN members new_members
     WHERE CURRENT_DATE - new_members.date_activated <= 1
           AND
           new_members.company_industry RLIKE ('[[:<:]](' || REPLACE(notify_members.notify_industry, '-', '|') || ')[[:>:]]');
```

Yuck.  Basically, you turn `9-13` into the [MySQL regular expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.htm) `[[:<:]](9|13)[[:>:]]`, which matches `9`, `13`, `13-27-61`, etc., but does not match `19-131` and the like.  (This supports a compound COMPANY_INDUSTRY field, too.)

Comment: Upvote.  Not because it's a solution that should actually be implmented (you don't think so either), but because it's an ingenious hack.

Comment: Thanks, @MikeRyan.  I'm pleased/saddened to say I get a number of upvotes from ugly/ingenious hacks. :)

Comment: +1 for the creativity and showing that sql can be art (art == something to look at but don't touch)

Comment: what are the disadvantages of implementing it?

Comment: +1 for good advice (don't do it!) whilst providing a creative solution (even though I'm half-tempted to addd -1 for even showing its possible in the current implementation ;-))

Comment: @OguguaBelonwu:  Breaking this type of data out into separate, normalized tables is the right thing to do.  This is what all the db design books say -- long experience has shown the benefits.  In your current design:  a) All changes/deletions of an industry/company will be as equally difficult as the answer you're trying to get here.  b) it will be slow -- normalized tables allow for the usage of indexes, etc. to allow solutions to scale -- this design will always require expensive, computation-laden table-scans, c) referential integrity is impossible, d) lots of other issues. . .

Comment: @MikeRyan thanks, i understand; will normalize the tables.
pilcrow, please the query does not behave as expected. Consider this query: "select email, contact_phone from members where notify_industry RLIKE ('[[:<:]](' || REPLACE($group, '-', '|') || ')[[:>:]]')"; if the $group is 1, the query returns rows with notify industry = 12, which is not suppose to. the query is only meant to match members with notify_industry = 1.

Comment: @OguguaBelonwu, sorry I can't reproduce that.  For me, `SELECT '12' RLIKE '[[:<:]](1)[[:>:]]';`, which is what your query should materially match on, is false.

Answer (score 12):

As @Shiplu pointed out, this is largely a normalization issue.  Despite what some people seem to think, multi-value columns are *murder* to try to get right.

Your basic issue is:
You have members, who are interested in one or more companies/industries, which belong to one or more industries.  You table structure should probably start as:

```
Industry
===============
id  -- autoincrement
name  -- varchar

Company
==============
id  -- autoincrement
name  -- varchar

Company_Industry
===============
companyId  -- fk reference to Company.id
industryId  -- fk reference to Industry.id

Member
===============
id  -- autoincrement
name  -- varchar
email  -- varchar

Member_Interest_Industry
=========================
memberId  -- fk reference to Member.id
industryId  -- fk reference to Industry.id

Member_Interest_Company
========================
memberId  -- fk reference to Member.id
companyId  -- fk reference to Company.id
```

To get all companies a member is interested in (directly, or through an industry), you can then run something like this:

```
SELECT a.name, a.email, c.name
FROM Member as a
JOIN Member_Interest_Company as b
ON b.memberId = a.id
JOIN Company as c
ON c.id = b.companyId
WHERE a.id = :inputParm
UNION 
SELECT a.name, a.email, d.name
FROM Member as a
JOIN Member_Interest_Industry as b
ON b.memberId = a.id
JOIN Company_Industry as c
ON c.industryId = b.industryId
JOIN Company as d
ON d.id = c.companyId
WHERE a.id = :inputParm
```

Answer (score 0):

Use join SQL syntax rather than a select in style..
You need to join the members table to itself.

Currently:

```
select id, email 
from members where notify_industry in 
  (select company_industry 
          from members 
           where datediff($today, date_activated) <= 1
  )
```

Use this style:

```
select m1.id, m1.email 
from members m1 
inner join members m2 on m1.company_industry = m.notify_industry
where datediff($today, m2.date_activated) <= 1
```

Note the use of aliasing to m1 and m2 to help understand which id and emails are returned.

Comment: Except `notify_industry` is a multi-value column, so changing it to a `JOIN` is going to have zero effect.  You could _attempt_ to add (multiple) `LIKE` predicate as part of the join, but it's going to be way more complicated and expensive than it would be to normalize the table

Answer (score 0):

This may get a little ugly but you could try the following

WARNING This will make a Cartesian Product worthy of any Mad Scientist

```
SELECT NotifyIndustry.id,NotifyIndustry.email
FROM
(
    SELECT CONCAT('-',COMPANY_INDUSTRY,'-') company FROM members
    WHERE datediff($today, date_activated) <= 1)"
) CompanyIndustry
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT CONCAT('-', NOTIFY_INDUSTRY,'-') who_to_notify
    FROM members
) NotifyIndustry
ON LOCATE(company,who_to_notify)>0;
```

Answer (score 0):

probably not the fastest query ever but this should do the job:

```
select m_to_notify.id, m_to_notify.email
from members m_to_notify
join members m_new_member
     on '-' || m_to_notify.notify_industry || '-'
     like '%-' || m_new_member.company_industry || '-%'
where datediff($today, m_new_memberdate_activated) <= 1)
```